# Vim C/C++/php auto replace . by -> when pointers

Tags: vim

Is there a plugin existing to auto replace `.` by `->` in insert mode when the variable referred is a pointer (C/C++) or an object in php ?
Else, is there an easy way to know the type of the expression just before the cursor to write my own script ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak for C/C++ mapping and I very much doubt there is a way to tell if a word in PHP is an object or not as PHP is weakly typed. However do have small script that I use for converting `.` to `->` that works well for me. Save [this script](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/9867672) as `~/.vim/ftplugin/php_this.vim` or `~/.vim/bundle/php_this/ftplugin/php_this.vim` if you are using pathogen.

Comment: ty, seems enough for php since '.' is the concatenation operator, and so shall interfere.